# Python sqlite3 update multiple rows with WHERE statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update multiple rows in my database with this code:

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect("usersEsteso.db")
        
        c = conn.cursor()

        record_id = name
        # query the database
        c.execute(f"""UPDATE usersEsteso SET
                f_name = :first,
                P_iva = :P_iva,
                cell_number = :cell_number,
                tax = :tax,
                inps = :inps

                WHERE f_name = f'{record_id}'""",
                  {
                      "first": f_name_entry.get(),
                      "P_iva": P_iva_entry.get(),
                      "cell_number": cell_number_entry.get(),
                      "tax": tax_entry.get(),
                      "inps": inps_entry.get(),
                  }

                  )

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

but the result is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Willow\WilloW SW Gestionale\schermata utenti 2.py", line 37, in save_edit
    c.execute(f"""UPDATE usersEsteso SET
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'sam'": syntax error
```

'sam' is the string inside the variable name

If I try to insert manually the string 'sam' inside the WHERE statement, the code works

Comment: are you sure your placeholder are correct? `:param`

Comment: @TheFool I think so... the code works if I insert manually the string 'sam' instead of f'{record_id}'
I think it could be a formatting issue:  I'm putting a " 'string' " where probably is necessary a "string" (WHERE statement)

Comment: why do you write it like that in the first place? Why dont you pass it als placeholder like the others?

Comment: @TheFool you're right, I've just realized it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved:

I used a placeholder in WHERE statement and assigned it in the dictionary below:

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect("usersEsteso.db")
        
        c = conn.cursor()

        record_id = name
        
        c.execute(f"""UPDATE usersEsteso SET
                f_name = :first,
                P_iva = :P_iva,
                cell_number = :cell_number,
                tax = :tax,
                inps = :inps

                WHERE f_name = :record""",
                  {
                      "first": f_name_entry.get(),
                      "P_iva": P_iva_entry.get(),
                      "cell_number": cell_number_entry.get(),
                      "tax": tax_entry.get(),
                      "inps": inps_entry.get(),
                      "record": record_id
                  }

                  )

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```